# FFmpeg on android is crashing in avcodec_decode_video2 function

Tags: android, ffmpeg, mpeg-4

FFmpeg is crashing on: libavcodec/utils.c avcodec_decode_video2 around line 2400

```
ret = avctx->codec->decode(avctx, picture, got_picture_ptr, &tmp);
```

So I've compiled ffmpeg on android using the following configure script (based from [here](https://github.com/cine-io/android-ffmpeg-with-rtmp) ):

```
prefix=${src_root}/ffmpeg/android/arm

addi_cflags="-marm -Os -fpic"
addi_ldflags=""

./configure \
--prefix=${prefix} \
--target-os=linux \
--arch=arm \
--enable-shared \
--disable-doc \
--disable-programs \
--disable-symver \
--cross-prefix=${TOOLCHAIN}/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
--enable-cross-compile \
--enable-decoder=aac \
--enable-decoder=mpeg4 \
--enable-decoder=h263 \
--enable-decoder=flv \
--enable-decoder=mpegvideo \
--enable-decoder=mpeg2video \
--sysroot=${SYSROOT} \
--extra-cflags="${addi_cflags}" \
--pkg-config=$(which pkg-config) >> ${build_log} 2>&1 || die "Couldn't configure ffmpeg"
```

The *.so files get copied over into my projects which I reference from my Android.mk script:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
FFMPEG_PATH=/path/to/android-ffmpeg-with-rtmp/build/dist

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libavcodec
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=$(FFMPEG_PATH)/lib/libavcodec-56.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libavdevice
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=$(FFMPEG_PATH)/lib/libavdevice-56.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libavfilter
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=$(FFMPEG_PATH)/lib/libavfilter-5.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libavformat
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=$(FFMPEG_PATH)/lib/libavformat-56.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libavutil
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=$(FFMPEG_PATH)/lib/libavutil-54.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libswresample
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=$(FFMPEG_PATH)/lib/libswresample-1.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libswscale
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=$(FFMPEG_PATH)/lib/libswscale-3.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(FFMPEG_PATH)/include
#LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := false
LOCAL_MODULE    := axonffmpeg
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libffmpeg.c
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -g
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libavcodec libavdevice libavfilter libavformat libavutil libswresample libswscale
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I'm building a little wrapper to decode frames (mpeg4 video,part 2 simple profile) that come from an external camera:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <android/log.h>

#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavutil/channel_layout.h>
#include <libavutil/common.h>
#include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
#include <libavutil/mathematics.h>
#include <libavutil/samplefmt.h>

#define DEBUG_TAG "LibFFMpeg:NDK"

AVCodec *codec;
AVFrame *current_frame;
AVCodecContext *context;

int resWidth, resHeight, bitRate;

void my_log_callback(void *ptr, int level, const char *fmt, va_list vargs);

jint Java_com_mycompany_axonv2_LibFFMpeg_initDecoder(JNIEnv * env, jobject this,
  jint _resWidth, jint _resHeight, jint _bitRate)
{
     __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "initDecoder called");

    int len;

    resWidth = _resWidth;
    resHeight = _resHeight;
    bitRate = _bitRate;
    av_log_set_callback(my_log_callback);
    av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_VERBOSE);
    avcodec_register_all();
    codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG4);
    if (!codec) {
      __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, DEBUG_TAG, "codec %d not found", AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG4);
      return -1;
    }
    context = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);    
    if (!context) {
      __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, DEBUG_TAG,  "Could not allocate codec context");
      return -1;
    }

    context->width = resWidth;
    context->height = resHeight;
    context->bit_rate = bitRate;
    context->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    context->time_base.den = 6;
    context->time_base.num = 1;
    int openRet = avcodec_open2(context, codec, NULL);
    if (openRet < 0) {
      __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, DEBUG_TAG,  "Could not open codec, error:%d", openRet);
      return -1;
    }
    current_frame = av_frame_alloc();    
    if (!current_frame) {
      __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, DEBUG_TAG,  "Could not allocate video frame");
      return -1;
    }    
    return 0;    
}


void my_log_callback(void *ptr, int level, const char *fmt, va_list vargs) {

  __android_log_print (level, DEBUG_TAG, fmt, vargs);

}

jint Java_com_mycompany_axonv2_LibFFMpeg_queueFrameForDecoding(JNIEnv * env, jobject this,
  jlong pts, jbyteArray jBuffer)
{

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "queueFrameForDecoding called");

    AVPacket avpkt;
    av_init_packet(&avpkt);
    int buffer_len = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, jBuffer);
    uint8_t* buffer = (uint8_t *) (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, jBuffer,0);
    int got_frame = 0;
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "copied %d bytes into uint8_t* buffer", buffer_len);

    av_packet_from_data(&avpkt, buffer, buffer_len);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "av_packet_from_data called");

    avpkt.pts = pts;
    int ret = avcodec_decode_video2(context, current_frame, &got_frame, &avpkt);

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "avcodec_decode_video2 returned %d" , ret);

    (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, jBuffer, (jbyte*) buffer, 0);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "ReleaseByteArrayElements()");

    return 0;
}
```

Alright so the init function above works fine and the queueFrameForDecoding works up until the avcodec_decode_video2 function. I'm not expecting it to work just quite yet however as I've been logging output as to where we get in that function, I've found that there is a call (in avutil.c):
(around line 2400 in the latest code)

```
avcodec_decode_video2(...) { 
   ....
        ret = avctx->codec->decode(avctx, picture, got_picture_ptr, &tmp);
```

init runs fine and finds the codec and all that. Everything works great up until the avcodec_decode_video2 call:

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/klteuc/klteatt:4.4.2/KOT49H/G900AUCU2ANG3:user/release-keys'
Revision: '14'
pid: 19355, tid: 22584, name: BluetoothReadTh  >>> com.mycompany.axonv2 <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
r0 79308400  r1 79491710  r2 7b0b4a70  r3 7b0b49e8
r4 79308400  r5 79491710  r6 00000000  r7 7b0b49e8
r8 7b0b4a70  r9 7b0b4a80  sl 795106d8  fp 00000000
ip 00000000  sp 7b0b49b8  lr 7ba05c18  pc 00000000  cpsr 600f0010
d0  206c616768616c62  d1  6564206365646f63
d2  756f722065646f63  d3  20736920656e6974
d4  0b0a01000a0a0a0b  d5  0a630a01000a0a0a
d6  0a630a011a00f80a  d7  0b130a011a00f90a
d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
d16 6369705f746f6720  d17 7274705f65727574
d18 8000000000000000  d19 00000b9e42bd5730
d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
d22 7b4fd10400000000  d23 773b894877483b68
d24 0000000000000000  d25 3fc2f112df3e5244
d26 40026bb1bbb55516  d27 0000000000000000
d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
scr 60000010
backtrace:
#00  pc 00000000  <unknown>
#01  pc 00635c14  /data/app-lib/com.mycompany.axonv2-6/libavcodec-56.so (avcodec_decode_video2+1128)
```

I don't understand why it's crashing when trying to call the decode function. I've looked into the codec function pointer list and this should be calling ff_h263_decode_frame (source, libavcodec/mpeg4videodec.c):

```
AVCodec ff_mpeg4_decoder = {
    .name                  = "mpeg4",
    .long_name             = NULL_IF_CONFIG_SMALL("MPEG-4 part 2"),
    .type                  = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO,
    .id                    = AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG4,
    .priv_data_size        = sizeof(Mpeg4DecContext),
    .init                  = decode_init,
    .close                 = ff_h263_decode_end,
    .decode                = ff_h263_decode_frame,
    .capabilities          = CODEC_CAP_DRAW_HORIZ_BAND | CODEC_CAP_DR1 |
                             CODEC_CAP_TRUNCATED | CODEC_CAP_DELAY |
                             CODEC_CAP_FRAME_THREADS,
    .flush                 = ff_mpeg_flush,
    .max_lowres            = 3,
    .pix_fmts              = ff_h263_hwaccel_pixfmt_list_420,
    .profiles              = NULL_IF_CONFIG_SMALL(mpeg4_video_profiles),
    .update_thread_context = ONLY_IF_THREADS_ENABLED(mpeg4_update_thread_context),
    .priv_class = &mpeg4_class,
};
```

I know that the ff_h263_decode_frame function isn't being called because I added logging to it and none of that gets printed.
However, if I just call ff_h263_decode_frame directly from avcodec_decode_video2 then my logging gets output. I don't want to call this function directly though and would rather get the ffmpeg framework working correctly. Is there something wrong with how I've configured ffmpeg? I have added mpegvideo, mpeg2video, flv, h263, to the configure script but none have them have helped (they should be included automatically by --enable-decoder=mpeg4).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG4);

That should be avcodec_find_decoder(), not avcodec_find_encoder(). Your decode call is failing/crashing because you opened an encoder, not a decoder, so the decode callback is NULL (which is why it dies with a NPE).

Comment: OMG! Thank you. Not sure how I overlooked that 1000 times but I did.